# Unable to implement Singleton Pattern

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Please have a look at the following code

**UIHandler.cpp**

```
#include "UIHandler.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



UIHandler::UIHandler()
{

}


UIHandler::~UIHandler(void)
{
}

UIHandler *UIHandler::getInstance()
{
    if(uiHandler==NULL)
    {
        uiHandler = new UIHandler();
    }

    return uiHandler;
}
```

**UIHandler.h**

```
#pragma once
class UIHandler
{
public:

    ~UIHandler(void);


    static UIHandler *getInstance();

private:

    UIHandler *uiHandler();
    UIHandler();
};
```

I am new to C++ and I am trying to implement the singleton pattern here. But, this one is giving errors! It says "`expression must be a modifiable lvalue`", in the place `uiHandler = new UIHandler();`

Why is this? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIHandler *uiHandler();` declares `uiHandler` as a method, not a data member. Change it to

```
static UIHandler *uiHandler;
```

The `static` is there because you're accessing it from a `static` method.

Note that a better way would be

```
UIHandler& UIHandler::getInstance()
{
    static UIHandler uiHandler;
    return uiHandler;
}
```

and just get rid of the member.

Don't forget to disallow copying.